# Apache POI set selected cell after xls document opens

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xls

We have next situation: our system has data export in xls format, this is huge file with many rows and columns.
And after user download and open document he see document scrolled to last column and last Spreadsheet tab. This is very annoying, better to set focus on first tab and first cell. I did simple test code to see how it works:

```
public class SelectionTest {
public static String file = "/usr/test/poi.test/src/main/resources/test";
@Test
public void test() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
    HSSFSheet s = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    s.setActive(true);
    HSSFRow row = s.getRow(0);
    HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);
    cell.setAsActiveCell();
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    wb.write(out);
    out.close();
}
}
```

And this doesn't works.

Comment: whats the log? I mean did you get any errors?

Comment: no, any errors, api just not works

Answer (score 7):

Here is working solution, have found this [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/poi-user@jakarta.apache.org/msg06137.html)

```
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
    HSSFSheet s = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    wb.setActiveSheet(0);
    s.showInPane(0, 0);
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    wb.write(out);
    out.close();
```

Comment: Looks alot like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5964598/701884) question and answer(s).

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work for me. I am using a XSSFWorkbook. That's the only difference.

Comment: Only works with HSSFWorkbook. For XSSFWorkbook you must use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44903464/is-there-any-way-to-move-horizontal-scroll-bar-the-sheet-one-column-to-the-left)

Answer (score 2):

**This worked for me:**

```
sheet.setActiveCell(new CellAddress(0, 0));
```