# Focus on first cell in excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file)); 
HSSFSheet s = wb.getSheetAt(0); 
wb.setActiveSheet(0);
s.showInPane(0, 0);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
wb.write(out);
out.close();
```

I am using above code for taking focus to first cell (when I open excel first cell shouldd be selected). It is opening the excel correctly because of `showInPane`, but selecting the first cell is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
HSSFSheet s = wb.getSheetAt(0);
s.setActive(true);
HSSFRow row = s.getRow(0);
HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);
cell.setAsActiveCell();
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Comment: setAsActiveCell is not working. Its not taking the focus to 1st cell.

Answer (score 2):

I recently stumbled on the same problem using POI 3.14. 
For me this worked:

`sheet.setActiveCell(new CellAddress(0, 0));`